# Is there a way to flip the touchbar icons?

Tags: touch-bar

Straightforward question: Is there a way to flip the buttons so the minimized control strip appears on the left and opens to the right, and so the escape button is stuck to the right of the bar? I constantly find myself accidentally hitting the buttons on the right since they are so close to the delete button.

Essentially, I'd like to mirror the two segments (control strip and esc button) of the touch bar shown below:

[image: Control strip and escape button]

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I understand your question current - BUT if I do, then here it goes.

If you open System Preferences=>Keyboard

[image]

Then you'll have a "Customize Control Strip..." button - which then allow you to build your own button order in the strip bar.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response - Currently this can't do what I'm trying to accomplish. In the touch bar, the collapsed control strip always appears on the right - you can't move it to the left - and the escape button appears on the left, you can't move it to the right. See edited post above with image.